# How can I securely make a minor update?

Tags: updating, 10

Once in about a month I make a minor update using the following commands.

```bash
cd website_directory
chmod u+w web/sites/default
composer update
vendor/bin/drush updatedb
vendor/bin/drush cache:rebuild
```

After adding write permissions to the user of the Drupal file tree and finishing the minor update, the permissions don't immediately come back to be what they were before, because [`system_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_requirements/9), which hardens Drupal permissions, won't necessarily immediately be called. Therefore, I believe I might do something wrong in the way I update Drupal, perhaps missing an essential command in Bash, or Composer, or Drush.

How to minor upgrade a core securely?

Comment: Do the composer update of core in CI and deploy the artifact to the hosting environment.

Comment: Okay, but what about `chmod u+w web/sites/default`, how to harden permissions immediately after an upgrade with that? `chmod u-w web/sites/default` and that's it (minusing the `write` permission from the `user`)?

Comment: Deploy with a user that can write to all areas.